# Difference between KeyEvent.getSource() and KeyEvent.getComponent()

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

What is the difference between `KeyEvent.getSource()` and `KeyEvent.getComponent()` and which one to use and when?
I'm creating some UI using KeyEvents.
I had to see there are the functions
 KeyEvent.getSource()
 KeyEvent.getComponent()
and was curious about which to use when.
Researches in the java api resulted in following:
 getSource() is inherited for EventObject with the following description:
 "The object on which the Event initially occurred."
 getComponent() is inherited from ComponentEvent
 "Returns the originator of the event."

Now it seems to me they return the same object with different types.

Therefore the question: Is that right and which one should I use?

Comment: You are correct.  In general, you want to write code that uses as little casting as possible;  code is more robust when types are checked at compile time rather than at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://coderanch.com/t/196784/java-programmer-OCPJP/certification/getSource-getComponent):

> `getSource()` is a method provided in the `AWTEvent` which is the abstract class for all the event classes. You call the `getSource()` method when you want to know what caused that action. This would be useful when you have an `actionEvent` that can be triggered by a button, a textfield or a menu item. You may want to know which item caused the action to fire and this call does that

Moreover the `getComponent()` method will return the `Component` object that was caught by the Event. So in the case of seeing what caused an action to fire, it doesn't make a real difference what you use to obtain the object that was interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc of each other:

---

**getSource():**

> Object java.util.EventObject.getSource()
>
> The object on which the `Event` initially occurred.
>
> Returns:The object on which the `Event` initially occurred.

---

**getComponent()**

> Component java.awt.event.ComponentEvent.getComponent()
>
> Returns the originator of the event.
>
> Returns:the `Component` object that originated the event, or `null` if the object is not a `Component`.

---

Conclusion:

1. `getSource()` returns an `Object`, which cannot be `null`, while `getComponent()` returns an `Component`, and sometimes, if `event instanceof Component == false`, it returns `null`.
2. Both need to be casted into your desired type. Of course, an `instanceof` check beforehand is always good. But, `getSource()` enables your a wider range and the casting can take longer but cannot be `null` (in my understanding).

So, use `e.getSource()` is always safer.

Answer (score 0):

in ComponentEvent, a superclass of KeyEvent:

```
public Component getComponent() {
    return (source instanceof Component) ? (Component)source : null;
}
```

and in EventObject, the *grandparent* of ComponentEvent (and KeyEvent):

```
protected transient Object  source;

public Object getSource() {
    return source;
}
```

*source code provided with JDK 1.8.0_121*

as can be seen both return the same Object (`source`) as long as it is a `Component`, if not, `getComponent` returns `null`.